# x cannot be resolved or is not a field y cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, generics

Main:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Foo<String, Location> foo = new Foo<>();
        foo.add("abc", new Location(5, 6));
    }
}
```

Location:

```
public class Location {
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public Location(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + x + "," + y + ")";
    }
}
```

Foo class:

```
public class Foo<K, T> {
    
    public void add(K name, T loc) {
        System.out.println(name + " " + loc.x + loc.y);
    }
    
    
}
```

When I try to run the program I get the "question title" error, I don't know what that happens, and how to fix that.

Comment: What if you create an instance of `Foo` that uses `Foo<String, String>`. What is `loc.x` going to be?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't make sense to access `x`. How can I fix that?

Comment: You've overridden the `toString()` method (which is part of the `Object` class) in your `Location` class. Generic types implicitly extend the `Object` class. You probably had to implement it (assuming this is an assignment), for this very reason.

Comment: @Ivar So there isn't any solution for this?

Comment: Depends on "this". If you want to use `loc.x` directly inside of the `add()` function, then  no. At least not as long as `loc` remains a generic type `T`. But nothing is stopping you from calling `loc.toString()` inside the `add()` method.

Comment: @Ivar So I have to extract the value of x and y from toString() right?

Comment: If you want to change the way `toString()` returns them... Otherwise you can just directly add the result of the `toString()` to the string you want to print. `System.out.println(name + " " + loc.toString())` (or even `System.out.println(name + " " + loc)`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use `instanceof` operator if you are expecting a type that you know. [This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/examples/InstanceofDemo.java) is a demo.

```
public void add(K name, T loc) {
    if(loc instanceof Location) {
        System.out.println(name + " " + ((Location)loc).x + ((Location)loc).y);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

As Stephen C mentioned that *`Foo` class potentially needs hard-coded knowledge of the capabilities of each of the possible types `T`. Which is (in theory) every Java reference type! The correct way to solve this is to declare `<T extends SomeInterface>` and provide getters in the interface to get the `x` and `y` attributes*

So instead of knowing about all possible types of `T` we can make `T` extend `SomeInterface` and get the information by calling the getters which can be implemented in the respective `type`.

Make `T` extend `LocationInfo` interface to get info about x and y

```
class Foo<K, T extends LocationInfo> {
    public void add(K name, T loc) {
        System.out.println(name + " " + loc.getX() + loc.getY());
    }
}

interface LocationInfo {
    int getX();
    int getY();
}
```

And include the implementation in `Location` class

```
class Location implements LocationInfo {
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public Location(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + x + "," + y + ")";
    }
    
    public int getX() { return x; }
    
    public int getY() { return y; }
}
```

Comment: This is an anti-pattern.  It means that the `Foo` class potentially needs hard-coded knowledge of the capabilities of each of the possible types `T`.  Which is (in theory) every Java reference type!  The correct way to solve this is to declare `<T extends SomeInterface>` and provide getters in the interface to get the `x` and `y` attributes.